# Averaging a list from a file and also find the min and max rate of change between each index Python

Tags: python-3.x

We received a file called USPopulation.txt, with instructions that basically say line 1 in the file is the year 1950 and the last line being 1990. we needed to store the data in a list and do 3 things with said data.

1. Find the average(somewhat easy i think i have this down)
2. Find the maximum rate of change in any 1 year
3. Find the minimum rate of change in any 1 year

## The Average of the numbers code taken from a past program

```
list_of_numbers = []
with open('USPopulation.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): 
            list_of_numbers.append(int(line.strip()))

print('Total ',len(list_of_numbers))
print('Average ',1.0 * sum(list_of_numbers) / len(list_of_numbers))
```

I need to combine the other elements and have no idea how any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *rate of change* is the difference between two subsequent values in the list. To get that value, you basically need to store the *previous* value and compare it to the current one.

One way of doing this would be to simply loop through your list, and collect those values:

```
previous = None:
ratesOfChange = []
for num in list_of_numbers:
    if previous:
        ratesOfChange.append(abs(num - previous))
    previous = num
```

Getting the maximum and minimum is then as easy as calling `max()` and `min()` on the `ratesOfChange` list.

Of course to improve this a bit, you might want to consider collecting those values while parsing the file already (so you save the second loop through the list). And you could even note down the minimum and maximum at the same time to save another loop through it (both `max` and `min` will loop over the list).

Answer (score 0):

if USPopulation.txt is like
1950=10000
1951=10005
1952=10030

then by converting the above lines into dictionary so that one can access each year and its corresponding population

file1 = open("USPopulation.txt", "r+")
years_dict = dict()
arr = []

class population:

```
def __init__(self):<br>
    self.average = 0
    self.maximum = 0
    self.minimum = 0

def average_method(self):
    try:
        for line in file1.readlines():
            value1 = line.split('=', 1)
            years_dict[value1[0]] = int(value1[1])
        length_of_dictionary = len(years_dict.keys())

        for values in years_dict.values():
            self.average = self.average + values

        self.average = (1.0 * self.average / length_of_dictionary)

    except:
        print "not able to read the lines from the file"

def maximum_method(self):
    try:
        i = 0 
        for year in range(1950, 1952):
            arr.insert(i, (years_dict[str(year + 1)] - years_dict[str(year)]))
            i = i + 1
        self.minimum = min(arr)
        self.maximum = max(arr)
    except:
        print "not able to insert the element"
```

obj = population()
obj.average_method()
 
obj.maximum_method()
print "Average of population: " + str(obj.average)
print "maximum rate of change: " + str(obj.maximum)
print "minimum rate of change: " + str(obj.minimum)